# As a freelance web-developer, where can I ask questions regarding portfolio building?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a freelance web developer but I don't have any work right now. My portfolio is dry.

Are there any sites within the network where I could ask questions related to the nuances of freelancing and portfolio building? Or perhaps even ones where I can look for work online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a site [where freelancers can ask and answer questions about the nuances of freelancing](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com), but that's *not* a site where you would go to look for work. That's the sort of place where you could find help on just better managing the aspects of working independently.

There are a few questions there that touch on the pros and cons of different freelance project services (elance, freelancer, etc) - but those serve more of a *what should I be looking for in such a service?* rather than *which of these is better for me?*.

You can go there, [have a look around](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/tour) and take a look at [what's on topic](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Before you ask a question, have a look at [the kinds of questions that really don't belong there](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - keep in mind it's objective Q&A and not the best place to get specific career-path guidance, even when it's focused on freelancing. It's more about the nuts-and-bolts that go into running your own one-person business.

While it might not suit your immediate need as well as you hoped, it's a great community and friendly bunch of folks - worth taking a few minutes to go see what they're all about.

Comment: Great. I guess this is the question that I'm sort of looking for. (:

Comment: There's an associated chat room (click the chat link in the site switcher once there) where you could probably ask folks where they're getting work aside from the 'major' sites. It's the sort of discussion best suited for chat. You'll need a tiny bit of rep on the site to be able to talk in chat, which you should be able to get by answering a single question or so.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* broad question.  I think you're going to want to be much more specific in order to get directed to the right sites.

Are you going to be asking for freelancer website recommendations (webapps, software recs, maybe)?

Are you asking for ideas on things to build for your portfolio (not sure about that one...)?

Are you asking for tutorial-style developer learning resources, as the title suggests (can't think of a site where this would be on topic)?

Or, are you asking something else?

*Update*: OP seems to have been asking where freelance jobs can be found, and the answer is: not here.  [StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) has [a few contract jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=contract), but there are definitely no freelance developer jobs on the Stack Exchange network.

[image: StackOverflow Careers]

Comment: I do not like freelancing websites because I have tried many such as odesk elance freelancer. It is too commercialised and very hard to find a project to take up. Are there any other places to find work? I need to build up on my portfolio by showcasing my works. But right now I do not have any. ):

Comment: @holyxiaoxin Careers 2.0 has some contract stuff (of varying terms). It's not the place where you'd find all of your work if you want to continue freelancing, but having a profile there definitely won't hurt (I had one the entire time I was a freelance systems programmer, prior to even working here, and I often pointed clients to it). I was also contacted about some positions, but was ultimately offered some short term stuff, because I indicated that's what I was after.

Comment: _"Are you going to be asking for freelancer website recommendations (webapps, software recs, maybe)?"_ Definitely **not** Web Apps.

Answer (score -4):

Two sites that you can look into are "Freelancer" and "Upwork". Users post what kind of job they need done, and you submit a bid with your price for the job. However, it may be tough to get your bid accepted if you have no work to show them and no reputation for your profile.

Comment: I realize the question kind of invites to post answers like this but I don't think we want a redirect list here to various jobboards across the internet.

Comment: I literally answered his exact question. "Are there any sites within the network where I could ask questions related to the nuances of freelancing and portfolio building? Or perhaps even ones where I can look for work online?"

Comment: Yes, you did. And we edited the question to make it fit within the scope of this particular site. Do know that recommendation questions are off-topic on almost all sites across the network because they attract answers that are either spam or go stale after a while. That is not a useful resource of knowledge to keep around. Above all there are probably more sites around there so this questions can have a dozen extra answers, replicating Google search. That is also not something that users of this site deem helpful.